# nth-child values and 2 col to 3 col

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've searched for this problem, but can't find an answer.

I have a file where I have 1 column on "mobile" and 2 columns on "tablet" and I'd like 3 columns on "desktop", or anything larger than 1100px.

I've tried a bunch of different nth-child values. It works from 1 to 2, but not 2 to 3. I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```css
/*Grid ------------------*/

/* Max out, center */

.image-grid {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.image-grid li {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-grid p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2% 0 5% 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.image-grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.image-grid li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: both;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/*Breaks ------------------*/

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .image-grid ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .image-grid li {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 0 4%;
  }
  .image-grid li a p {
    font-size: 1.65rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
  .image-grid p {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  .image-grid li {
    float: left;
    width: 31.3333%;
    margin: 1.5%;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
  .image-grid li:nth-child(4) {
    clear: right;
    background: aqua;
  }
  .image-grid {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <ul class="image-grid">
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/logos.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0007_WHT_web_logos-06.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/logos.html">Logos</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/akqa.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0011_WHT_web_AKQA-MAIN.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/akqa.html">AKQA</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/nike2021.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0004_WHT_web_Nike2021_8.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/nike2021.html">Nike 2021</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/gimme5.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0009_WHT_web_Gimme5-02.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/gimme5.html">Walnut's Gimme 5</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/xbox.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0000_WHT_web_Halo-03.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/xbox.html">Xbox Master Chief Collection</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/opolis.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0003_WHT_web_Opolis-13.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/opolis.html">Opolis Design</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/votesolar.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0002_WHT_web_VoteSolar-05.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/votesolar.html">Vote Solar</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/nikeevents.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0005_WHT_web_Nike-Sales-Rec_1_0.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/nikeevents.html">Nike Sales Events</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/classicben.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0010_WHT_web_Classic-Ben-05.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/classicben.html">Classic Ben</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/medigap.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0006_Medigap-N1_Who-is-AC.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/medigap.html">AllCare Medigap</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/levi.html">
          <img src="http://jonschafer.com/gfx/-main/gfx-main_0008_WHT_web_Levi-06.jpg" alt="" />
          <p><a href="http://jonschafer.com/portfolio/levi.html">Levi</a>
          </p>
        </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!-- End group -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/change the following properties within the 1100px media query:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
    .image-grid li {
        margin: 1%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .image-grid li:nth-child(odd) {
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

The issues with your code are:

1. You have odd columns clearing, which isn't needed with a three column layout
2. Your margin is set to 1.5%. So the combined width of each li is 34.3333%, too wide to fit three on one row.
3. Each li has a 1px border, so even with 1% margins for 33.3333% total width, the 1px border will push the third item to the next line. `box-sizing: border-box` includes the border in the li's width, so the element is truly 33.3333% width.

Comment: Are you sure you added the properties correctly? I just tested and that is working.

Comment: send me a snippet? i tried your and @stephenbolton's solution but neither worked. to be clear, this is my code:

`@media (min-width: 1100px) {
 body {
  background: green;
 }
 
 .image-grid p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }
 
    .image-grid li {
     float: left;
        width: 33.3333%;
        margin: 1%;
        background: bisque;
    }
    
 .image-grid li:nth-child(odd) {
   clear: both;
 }
 
 .image-grid {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
 }
}`

Comment: Here's a working fiddle with my changes: https://jsfiddle.net/zb8w2yft/ Just resize the window so the 1100px media query comes into effect.

Comment: Thanks Josh. That worked. Although, I was able to remove the "nth-child(4)" and it still has 3 columns. What was I getting wrong?

Comment: There's really no need to use :nth-child for this particular layout. Since the items are all a fixed width of 33.3333% and floated left, every fourth item will automatically 'clear' to the next line, since there's no available space on the line above. They keys were the margin and box sizing, allowing three elements to fit on one line.

Comment: i now understand the margin and box-sizing thing. but when i remove the nth-child section, it no longer works as 3.

Comment: Not sure which rule you'r referring to. You can remove every instance of nth-child from the fiddle without breaking the layout, although that may not contain your full code.

Comment: whoa! that's awesome. i removed all instances of the nth-child and it still works great. lovely. thanks! #magic

Comment: Yep, no need to over complicate it with :nth-child rules :) No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

its because you never overwrote this rule:

`.image-grid li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: both;
}`

So the third item is clearing both sides.

Comment: hmm, that didn't work either. here's my snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/whyhellothere/k5t3dawd/embedded/result/

Comment: After looking at Josh's snippet, I now understand what you mean. Thanks! 

Just to be clear:

clear:both means that the 3rd column was going to the next row. And my margin was too big which also was pushing my content down. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me :

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  /*keep all others*/

  /**remove this one
    .image-grid li:nth-child(2n+1) {
      clear: both;
    }
  */

  /* modify this one*/
  .image-grid li {
    float: left;
    width: 31.3333%;
    margin: 1%; /* Change from 1.5% */
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*Added this line*/
  }
```

Hope it helps T04435.